# spring scheduled task run every second with cron(0 0/10 * * * ? )

Tags: cron, spring-scheduled

it's strange, i setup corn as

```
@Scheduled(cron= "0 0/10 *  * * ? ")
```

It did trigger every 10 minutes,
but the issue is task runs each second.

Answer (score 18):

This is what javadoc says :

[CronSequenceGenerator](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html)

the first field of the cron is for seconds.

Comment: How to make it run every second ?

Comment: Doc says "*/10 * * * * *" = every ten seconds. so the expression for every second would be "*/1 * * * * *"

Comment: I tried your suggestion, @Farsee and have to say that in my case the job runs every ten minutes, not seconds

Answer (score 5):

If you want to execute every 10 seconds, you should have this:

```
@Scheduled(cron= "0/10 * * ? * *")
```